# How to apply the same style on several rows and columns?

Tags: css

How to apply the same style on several rows and columns ?
Here is the relevant page :

https://dev.s1biose.com/produit

I applied style on the produce "Chocolat noir artisanal BIO enrobant des noisettes" and I wish to apply them on other products.

Here's my style sheet :

```
.views-teaser-variation #edit-purchased-entity-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.views-teaser-variation #edit-submit {
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width: 60%;
}

.views-teaser-variation #edit-quantity-0-value {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 40%;
}

.views-teaser-variation #edit-quantity-wrapper .form-inline .control-label {
    display: none;
}

.views-teaser-variation #edit-wishlist {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to target dynamically generate id like `#edit-purchased-entity-wrapper--2`, `#edit-purchased-entity-wrapper--3` etc. These IDs value begins with a specified value so it is good to use attribute selector. ex:

```
.views-teaser-variation [id^=edit-purchased-entity-wrapper]
```

will target those and apply the CSS:

```
#edit-purchased-entity-wrapper
#edit-purchased-entity-wrapper--2
#edit-purchased-entity-wrapper--3
#edit-purchased-entity-wrapper--4
#edit-purchased-entity-wrapper--5
#edit-purchased-entity-wrapper--6
```

Also, try to be more specific when you target the element, to read more:

> ### CSS [attribute^="value"] Selector
>
> The [attribute^="value"] selector is used to select elements whose attribute value begins with a specified value.
>
> The following example selects all elements with a class attribute value that begins with "top":
>
> Note: The value does not have to be a whole word!
>
> ref: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

NOTE: It is better to use a `class` to apply the same style if you have control to the dynamically generated HTML items. Otherwise, it is ok to use attribute selector, just make sure to be specific when you target the correct elements you want (if not, you might apply the style to the element you don't want).

```css
.views-teaser-variation [id^=edit-purchased-entity-wrapper] {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}


.views-teaser-variation [id^=edit-submit] {
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width: 60%;
}

.views-teaser-variation input[id^=edit-quantity-0-value] {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 40%;
}

.views-teaser-variation [id^=edit-quantity-wrapper] .form-inline .control-label {
    display: none;
}

.views-teaser-variation [id^=edit-wishlist] {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is it supported by all browsers ?

Comment: This is very cool, but I would not say this is the right way to reason about it. It addresses the issue - but doesn't address that the underlying HTML is trouble. All of this can *and should* be done with classes.

Comment: There should only be 1 of each ID per page... so - this works - but is about as against the grain as you could get.

Comment: @Mathieu it is since CSS 2.1 which covered like 98.26% browsers.  ref: http://caniuse.com/#search=attribute%20selector

Comment: @sheriffderek I think those id are generated from template he is using (and generated dynamically), so generated id are something like `#edit-purchased-entity-wrapper--2` and `#edit-purchased-entity-wrapper--3` so totally fine.

Comment: Ah - I can see that. They should still just style the base class though. `<div class="col col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 views-teaser>...` is a masterpiece of nonsense though - so, I'll leave it be. : )

Comment: @sheriffderek Cool, I also updated my description, suggest to use a class if it is possible, if not, it is cool to use attribute selector but must be specific when target the correct element, otherwise it is gonna mess up some styling.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how the styles 'cascade' down. If you want to apply style to the rows, you can just use a common class on their parent element and write style rules for that class. The short answer might be "don't use ID's for styling" - I'm not sure of the use-case.

I'll use a few lists to illustrate the point.

markup

```
<ul class='item-list'>
  <li class='item'>one</li>
  <li class='item'>two</li>
  <li class='item'>three</li>
</ul>

<ul class='item-list dark'>
  <li class='item'>one</li>
  <li class='item'>two</li>
  <li class='item'>three</li>
</ul>

<ul class='item-list'>
  <li class='item'>one</li>
  <li class='item'>two</li>
  <li class='item'>three</li>
</ul>
```

styles

```
ul { /* targets ALL unordered lists */
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item-list { /* targets anything with this class (in  case the ul) */
  color: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
/* you could write    ul.item-list   if you wanted to be more specific... */

.item-list.dark { /* anything with BOTH of these classes */
  color: navy;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/5xjqnv23/